# On Heroku, can I use Rails to serve a generated audio file back to my React Native front-end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, react-native, heroku, expo

I'm generating temporary audio files using Rails and storing them in the `tmp` directory in Heroku.  I think want to send the audio back to Expo/React Native to be played.  How can I use Rails to serve that data as a POST response?

In my Rails API backend, I connect to a Text-to-Speech API (Google), and generate an mp3 from text.  I can verify that these files are being correctly created and stored in `tmp` as per my POST request.  I am missing the conceptual piece of how to return them back.

It's ideal for me that these files are temporary, as I only need them during a single session.  I can see a couple of options.

1. I can save the files as .mp3s in `tmp`, as I'm currently doing, and find a way to attach them to my POST response.
2. I get the audio back from the API as binary, so I can skip saving the files as .mp3s, and respond to the POST with the binary as JSON, or something.
3. ???
4. Play sound in Expo/ React Native

I'm trying to avoid setting up an AWS bucket for this if possible, but if that's the best way to do it, I'm happy to hear that as well.

Thanks!

Comment: in your controller you can do `send_file "/path/to/file.mp3", type: "audio/mp3", filename: "filename.mp3"` as response

Comment: That's excellent, thank you for the lead.